# Jquery String + Object + String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

I have a small issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

Here goes... I have an input being created like this...

```
var input = $('<input/>');
```

If I do this....all is good

```
$(this).append(input);
```

If I do this though....

```
$(this).append('<div>' + input + '</div>');
```

It appends a div with the html `[object Object]`

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `+` is for concatenating strings. `input` is a jQuery object, not a string.

Comment: I knew this was the issue, I was just not sure if there was a function to convert an object to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could

```
$('<div />').append(input).appendTo(this);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fhqyd9pb/)

The problem is `input` is an jQuery object so when you use it in a string concatenation it will result in `[object Object]`(default `toString()` for an object);

---

Or

```
var input = $('<input/>');
$('<div />', {
    append: input
}).appendTo(this);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fhqyd9pb/2/)

Comment: Is there a method or function to turn an object into a string?

Comment: @VIDesignz see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852750/jquery-string-object-string/25852764#answer-25852778) by [trueblueaussie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/trueblueaussie)- if you want it as a string then why are you creating it as an jQuery object

Comment: I find it easier to create as an object, but your question is valid. Is it advisable to just work with objects rather than strings when creating elements?

Comment: @VIDesignz I would mostly work with objects... but then at the end I would use that object not the generated string... else I would try to generate the markup directly using strings

Comment: @VIDesignz why do you want to have the html for your concatenation where you could easily use the object itself

Comment: I agree with your last statement, sometimes it is easier to just use a string and other times use an object, I realize now I should commit to either/or. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with all strings, or all jQuery objects:

e.g.

```
$(this).append($('<div>').append(input));
```

or

```
$(this).append('<div>' + input[0].outerHTML + '</div>');
// I think this version is ugly :)
```

Notes:

- `$('<div>')` creates a new jQuery DOM element, which can then have child content appended.
- `input[0].outerHTML` will return the text string equivalent to the DOM objects HTML

Comment: I don't think `input.html()` will work as `.html()` will return `innerHTML`... `input` element does not have `innerHTML`

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Yep, too quick. Corrected (horrible solution though)

Comment: Although all the other answers are pretty much the same, I was after a solution to which could convert an object to a string. This seems to be the way.

Comment: Not as pretty, but the DOM `outerHTML` will do the trick. Good luck with your project.